# Incompatible types for return

Tags: c, debugging, pointers

Sorry if this is an overly simple question. I am just very frustrated.

While compiling, I receive the following error:

```
sll.c:129: error: incompatible types in return
```

Here is my structure definition at the top of my file, it might be necessary to understand the function in which the error occurs:

```
struct string_linked_list {
   char *s;
   struct string_linked_list *next;
};

typedef struct string_linked_list SLL;
```

Here is the function which returns the error. I wrote the function to simply construct a singleton list for testing purposes.

```
SLL makeSingleton()
{
    SLL * new= (SLL *) malloc( sizeof(SLL));
    char*sp = strdup("test");
    new->s = sp;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What is the return type of `makeSingleton`. is it `SLL*`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I miscopied my code. I included SLL, but forgot the *, is that necessary?

Comment: Yes. the return type is a pointer and hence, you need to include' `SLL*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function has an *implicit* return type of int, while you return SLL*
also try to avoid naming variables "new"

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify your return type:

```
SLL* makeSingleton()
{
```

If you don't specify this, in C, the function will default to returning int.

---

Edit:

Given your new edit, the issue is that you need to make the return type `SLL*`, not `SLL`:

```
SLL* makeSingleton()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Reed! I don't know howI overlooked this!

Answer (score 2):

In your program the return type is a pointer and hence, the footprint of the program should be `SLL* makeSingleton`